# Window.open to call an Action in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

I want to call an Action on a `Window.open` function.

I have this on my view:

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('icon-picture.png', array('alt' => 'fotos', 'class'=>'link-fotos', 'onClick' => "window.open('".$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'Pedidos' ,'action'=>'exibeFotos'))."', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=770, HEIGHT=400')", 'id' => 'dialogFotos')),
    array('escape' => false));
```

But the result is:
[image: Result]

I don't get it what I'm doing wrong. Syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The options array needs to be the **third parameter** in `$this->Html->link()`. You have it being passed as the **second parameter**, so it is not properly rendering the `"escape=>false"` option...

Try this:

```
$this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('icon-picture.png', array('alt' => 'fotos', 'class'=>'link-fotos', 'onClick' => "window.open('".$this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'Pedidos' ,'action'=>'exibeFotos'))."', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=770, HEIGHT=400'); return false;", 'id' => 'dialogFotos')),
    '#',
    array('escape' => false)
);
```

This just adds an empty anchor to the link, and adds `return false;` to the end of your `onClick` event so it does not follow the link after it opens the new window.